# using a lookup table in R with varying counts of data

Tags: r, match, lookup

Hiiii, I've been working on this issue all weekend.  I'm trying to do a simple lookup, but my lookup table has different counts of data per lookup key.

Let's say I have two tables:
Table1: (there are some extra columns of data, but irrelevant to my problem)
Table1: (sample of 3 rows)

```
GeneName
col1      col2
HGGR      .554444  
BRAC4     .333222
FAM34     .111222
```

My lookup table is table of Gene groups followed by their respective genes. The lookup table can varying amount of columns depending on how many genes are in the group... This is a small example, the table often has 20-30 genes per group...
Table2: (example of 2 rows)

```
GeneGroupName
col1              col2      col3
CHR1_45000_46000  HGGR      BRAC4
CHR1_67000_70000  FAM34
```

What I want is another column in Table1 which shows the corresponding gene group!

```
FinalResultTable

    col1                col2      col3
    CHR1_45000_46000    HGGR      .554444 
    CHR1_45000_46000    BRAC4     .333222
    CHR1_67000_70000    FAM34     .111222
```

The code I have so far is:

```
finalresult<-cbind( gene_group[match(table1[,1], gene_group[,2]),1], table1)
```

but of course that only works for genes found in the 2nd column of the gene group table!  I need it to search thru the whole table and return the row number....

Any help?  Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert your Table 2 to long format, with a column for `GeneGroupName` and a single column for the member genes, and *then* use `match`.

```
(table1 <- data.frame(GeneName=sample(LETTERS[1:12]), col2=runif(12)))

#    GeneName      col2
# 1         F 0.6116285
# 2         L 0.5752088
# 3         J 0.7499011
# 4         D 0.9405068
# 5         A 0.9360968
# 6         K 0.6549850
# 7         I 0.7070163
# 8         E 0.3521952
# 9         C 0.4234293
# 10        G 0.7750203
# 11        B 0.1418680
# 12        H 0.6632382

(table2 <- data.frame(GeneGroupName=1:4, g1=LETTERS[1:4], g2=LETTERS[5:8],
                      g3=LETTERS[9:12]))

#   GeneGroupName g1 g2 g3
# 1             1  A  E  I
# 2             2  B  F  J
# 3             3  C  G  K
# 4             4  D  H  L

(table2.long <- reshape(table2, direction='long', varying=list(-1), timevar='gene'))

#     GeneGroupName gene g1 id
# 1.1             1    1  A  1
# 2.1             2    1  B  2
# 3.1             3    1  C  3
# 4.1             4    1  D  4
# 1.2             1    2  E  1
# 2.2             2    2  F  2
# 3.2             3    2  G  3
# 4.2             4    2  H  4
# 1.3             1    3  I  1
# 2.3             2    3  J  2
# 3.3             3    3  K  3
# 4.3             4    3  L  4

table1$grp <- table2.long$GeneGroupName[match(table1$GeneName, 
                                              table2.long$g1)]

table1

#    GeneName      col2 GeneGroupName
# 1         F 0.6116285             2
# 2         L 0.5752088             4
# 3         J 0.7499011             2
# 4         D 0.9405068             4
# 5         A 0.9360968             1
# 6         K 0.6549850             3
# 7         I 0.7070163             1
# 8         E 0.3521952             1
# 9         C 0.4234293             3
# 10        G 0.7750203             3
# 11        B 0.1418680             2
# 12        H 0.6632382             4
```

Answer (score 1):

On solution could be to use the `data.table` package.
Reproducing an atomic example:

```
table1 = data.table(col1=c("HGGR","BRAC4","FAM34"),col2=c(.55,.33,.11))
table2 = data.table(col2=c("HGGR","FAM34"),col1=c("CHR1_45000_46000", "CHR1_67000_70000"), col3=c("BRAC4",NA))

# > table1
#     col1 col2
# 1: BRAC4 0.33
# 2: FAM34 0.11
# 3:  HGGR 0.55

# > table2
#     col2             col1  col3
# 1:  HGGR CHR1_45000_46000 BRAC4
# 2: FAM34 CHR1_67000_70000    NA
```

First deal with the second `data.table` to merge `col2` and `col3` with `melt`:

```
table2=melt(table2, id=c("col1"), value.name="col2", na.rm=TRUE)
table2[,variable:=NULL]
```

Then merge the two `data.table` to get the wanted result:

```
setkey(table1, col1)
setkey(table2, col2)
table2[table1]

# col2   col1               col2.1
# BRAC4  CHR1_45000_46000   0.33
# FAM34  CHR1_67000_70000   0.11
# HGGR   CHR1_45000_46000   0.55
```

Answer (score 0):

Modying @jbaums's sample data a bit (adding NA in table2), here is one way with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
table1 <- data.frame(GeneName=sample(LETTERS[1:12]), col2=runif(12),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table2 <- data.frame(GeneGroupName=1:4, g1=LETTERS[1:4], g2=LETTERS[5:8],
          g3=c(LETTERS[9:11], NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


table2 %>%
    gather(gene, whatever, - GeneGroupName) %>%
    left_join(., table1, by = c("whatever" = "GeneName")) %>%
    select(-gene, GeneGroupName, gene = whatever, value = col2)


#   GeneGroupName gene     value
#1              1    A 0.9926841
#2              2    B 0.3531973
#3              3    C 0.6547239
#4              4    D 0.4781180
#5              1    E 0.1293723
#6              2    F 0.6334933
#7              3    G 0.2132081
#8              4    H 0.5987610
#9              1    I 0.7317925
#10             2    J 0.9761707
#11             3    K 0.9240745
#12             4 <NA>        NA
```